# How to configure Spring Boot 2 WebFlux to use SSL?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, keytool

All I get is `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common`.

This is how to reproduce the behavior:

- go to http://start.spring.io and add "Reactive Web" as dependency for Spring 2.0.1
- unpack the archive
- run `keytool -genkeypair -keystore demo/src/main/resources/keystore.jks`

  - Choose a password
  - Hit return as long as `[Unknown]` is the default, enter `Yes` when asked if `CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, ...` is correct.
  - Use the same password for the key as for the keystore
- add the following to application.properties

  ```
  server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
  server.ssl.key-store-password=<my-secure-pwd>
  ```
- build and run the application
- run `curl https://localhost:8080`

This is my first time adding SSL to a Spring Boot application and I think that something must be wrong - but I've no idea what. Maybe anyone of you could provide some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, turns out that you need to set the key algorithm to RSA in order to make this work.

`keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keystore src/main/resources/keystore.jks`